# Problemas con JSF Jboss Tools en eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jsf, jboss

Al momento de querer crear un JSF project me aparece el siguiente error, he buscado y buscado y no doy con el problema, quisiera que me dijeran si ya les ha pasado algo así y cómo lo solucionaron, se los agradecería mucho.[image: Imagen de error]

Comment: Haz probado con hacer backup de tus proyectos y volver a reinstalar tu eclipse

Comment: No, gracias por la sugerencia lo haré y te confirmo si funciono gracias.

Comment: He solucionado el problema, solo cambie de directorio de proyecto pero, de no haber sido por tu sugerencia no lo habría logrado muchas gracias por la ayuda.